# Analysis Apps for iOS10/64Bit

Tags: ios

I need to analyze an iOS app. Since it's iOS 10 64Bit (jailbroken) this time, I'm desperately looking for good analysis tools for injecting, manipulating, anti-anti-jailbreak, tracing, and so on. I previously used tools iRet and iSpy and so on, but none of those tools are available for iOS10 64Bit it seems. Any helping input on how to analyze apps in this environment would be really appreciated. (at least Keychaindumper still works ;)

Comment: Did you ever find anything of value for this? Having the same dilemma myself. Thanks